# Chart's Y-axis does not re-render properly in Billboard.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, billboard.js

There is a chart generated in Billboard.js which has the possibility to introduce custom values as minimum and maximum for the Y-axis.

The problem that I encounter is that even the axis is changing when the values are modified, they are not very close to the introduced value.

For example this screenshot:

[image]

On the maximum value I don't think it is a great problem. But on the minimum one it is. The default value was 0, after there was introduced 300 I would expect to start from a closer value to it, not 0 as before. The Y-axis just moved few pixels after that change.

The html code:

```
<input type="number" ng-change="$ctrl.updateY('max')" ng-model="$ctrl.max">
```

The JS code:

```
updateY(val) {
    if(val=== 'max') {
        if(this.max || this.max === 0) {
            this.maxValue = this.max;
        }
    } else {
        if(this.min || this.min === 0) {
            this.minValue = this.min;
        }
    }
    const maxNumber = Number(this.maxValue);
    const minNumber = Number(this.minValue);
    this.lineView.chart.axis.range({max: {y: maxNumber}, min: {y: minNumber}});
    this.resetY = false;
}
```

This is the code for `max`, same one for `min`.

I think that maybe the problem is from [range](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#API.AxisRange), it doesn't generate the Y-axis with the values introduced.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a working reproducible demo? and what is the value for the orange color line?

Comment: probably it's very difficult to make a working demo for this one. the value for orange line it's between 0 and 20 most of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rendering much closer to the introduced values if it is added a padding in `bb.generate`:

```
const chart = bb.generate({
...
"axis": {
...
"y": {
...
        "padding" : {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 10
        }

...
```